# Eclipse, customize Content Assist content

Tags: eclipse, editor

I've tried searching for help on how to customize the auto complete commands for Content Assist in the Eclipse editor.

I.e when i type "var_dump($expression)" and press enter the variable "$expression" gets highlighted including the dollar sign. In my opinion it would be more convenient if only the word "expression" were selected.

So does anyone how I can customize these kind of rules.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

imho you're talking about php. you should contact the PHPEclipse (if youre using their plugin) and ask them to add an option to be able to disable the highlighting of the dollar-sign when highlighting variables.

best way to get a feature done is by doing it by implementing it by yourself and sending them a patch. thanks to open source the code of phpeclipse is available. you should start here 
-> http://www.phpeclipse.com/browser/trunk/net.sourceforge.phpeclipse.ui/src/net/sourceforge/phpeclipse/phpeditor/util

don't forget to add an option to the code formatter options!
-> http://www.phpeclipse.com/browser/trunk/net.sourceforge.phpeclipse.ui/src/net/sourceforge/phpeclipse/preferences